# Is there a maximum horizontal acceleration for passengers?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, takeoff, passenger, g-forces

Are there any regulations regarding the maximum acceleration forces that passengers should experience during takeoff/flight/landing?

Or what would be considered to be an acceptable horizontal acceleration? 0.5g? 1g?

I am contemplating how to achieve very good STOL characteristics for a small  commuter aircraft while still maintaining a high wing loading.

Comment: I really like the question as a passenger plane is long and passengers from different parts of the airplane may experience different accelerations depending on the combination of linear and angular accelerations.

Comment: What sort of scheme were you planning to use that would come anywhere close to this: rocket assisted takeoff?  A steam or electromagnet catapult?  I suspect you'll be limited by economics more than passenger comfort.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am not really sure yet. But considering that all these VTOL startups need to achieve a thrust-to-weight ratio >1, a thrust-to-weight ratio around 0.5 and therefore an acceleration around 0.5g might be feasible for a slightly larger aircraft (about a dozen passengers). I don't think rockets or catapults make sense from an economical or operational point of view.

Comment: Australian document [AS 3533.1](https://ablis.business.gov.au/service/wa/australian-standard-as-3533-amusement-rides-and-devices/17504) [prescribes a maximum 2g/3g](http://www.hse.gov.uk/research/hsl_pdf/2002/hsl02-07.pdf) for amusement ride, so you have some freedom. Note that very high accelerations are acceptable (30g if you wish) but not for any duration. When coughing, the body experiences a 3g acceleration. This is the key: how long will it last?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on several factors:
1) How long is the body subjected to these forces?
2) What's the posture of the body?
3) To what extent are the passengers used to g forces (for example due to training)?
...

However, early experiments showed that untrained humans could withstand g forces as much as 20 g for less than 10 seconds, to 10 g for 1 minute, and 6 g for 10 minutes.